# Office 365 Sharepoint missing some workflows?

Tags: workflow, office-365

I'm trying to set up a document approval workflow as well as a signature collection workflow in our Office 365 (E3) sharepoint.  However, there are only 2 workflows available to choose from (see attached image)

[image: Available workflows]

Comment: Hi i have had the same issue with SharePoint Online, its fixed for me i used this explanation http://blogs.msmvps.com/cgross/2011/11/09/approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010-server-office-365/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go to Site Settings > Site collection features (under Site Collection Administration header) could you check if you have following feature available: Workflows and if it's not enabled, enable it. Checked on my O365 account and it worked :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: If Workflows site collection feature is activated, but those workflows are not enabled, reactivate the feature. Hope this info will help somebody :)

Answer (score 8):

I had to deactivate and reactivate the Workflows setting in the Site Settings collection, Site features to get the 2010 templates to show up in O365.

Comment: This really Helped... Deactivate & then reactivate the feature

Comment: I had to deactivate and reactive Workflows in Site Features to get them to show up thank you @user56279

Answer (score 1):

I also had to activate the site-level 'Team Collaboration Lists' feature, before the Workflow Settings option would appear for lists/libraries.  I think it has something to do with the need for the Tasks list.

[image]